# Send GA Event Before Redirection to external website

Tags: javascript, php, google-analytics, google-tag-manager

How to make sure that Google analytics received the event i sent from my website before redirecting to external website using javascript, and also make sure that the redirection happen if the GA/GTM code was blocked on users's browser?

I know that delaying the redirection or doing the redirection via GTM can solve that issue but delaying approach could be annoying and affect the user experience a bit negatively and doing the redirection through GTM can cause the redirection to fail if the user browser was blocking the GTM/GA tracking

You can check the sourcecode of the redirect page here
https://bonvivo.de/amazon/

Answer (score 0):

Analytics has a specific `hitCallback` feature that allows you to run some code right after the data were sent to analytics servers. Redirection is one of the supposed use for this.
Analytics [developer documentation has some good examples](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/sending-hits#hitcallback) of this, including handling timeouts.